# Why can I upload a file, but not download it without getting an Out of Memory Exception?

Tags: c#, .net, file, exception, out-of-memory

My software has a feature that allows users to upload files which are stored as byte strings in my database.
The code works like this:

The number of bytes in the file is calculated, and a byte array is created that has that length.  The file is then read into the byte array.  From here, the file is split into pieces and stored in my database.  This is done by using the following code:

```
openFile1 = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
blah, blah, blah
.
.
.
openFileBytesNumber = openFile1.Length;
byteArray = new byte[openFileBytesNumber];
openFile1.Read(byteArray, 0, (int)(openFileBytesNumber));
fullByteString = Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray);
```

When I download it, the following happens:

A byte string is created by loading the file data from the database and concatenating all the pieces.  The string is put into a byte array using the following line of code:

```
byteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(byteString.ToString());
```

This is where I get an out of memory exception.  Why am I getting the OutOfMemoryException on the download, but not the upload?

Comment: What is `byteString` and how do you concatenate the pieces?

Comment: .NET needs to allocate a contiguous block of memory.  If the file is large, it may be that it just does not find enough contiguous memory for the second allocation.  Storing the file as a Base64 string is very wasteful.  It should be stored in a binary column.

Comment: @Guffa,

    StringBuilder byteString = new StringBuilder();

     for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    byteString.Append(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["data"].ToString());
                }

Comment: _Why am I getting the OutOfMemoryException on the download, but not the upload?_ Do you mean you __always__ get the OOM error, no matter what the file size? __What sizes__ are we talking about here?

Comment: @SeanSmyth Can you break up the byteString into chunks and decode it that way? Any reason why you need the whole thing in memory? (In other words, don't assemble, just decode it a piece at a time.)

Comment: You are reading __all__ rows from your table. Is that really right?? I would expect you only want the rows for that one file.. or are you filling the table that way anyway? (Just wondering..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base64 has a 30% overhead, and strings have a 100% overhead (as a `char` is 16 bits). That makes a 160% overhead (1.3 * 2.0 = 2.6) for keeping the data as a base64 string in memory.

You are keeping all the data in the `DataSet` in memory, along with the `StringBuilder`, along with the final string, along with the final result. That's a total overhead of 780% (3 * 2.6 + 1 = 8.8).

The code requires roughly 9 times as much memory as the file size.

To reduce the memory usage you can:

- Use a data reader instead of a data set. That way you only have one record at a time in memory.
- Do the conversion from base64 to bytes on each record instead of building the whole string. That can be done if the string length is evenly divisable by four.

---

Side note: You are using the `Read` method wrong when you are reading the file. The `Read` method returns the number of bytes read, which may be smaller than the number of bytes requested. You need to get the return value from the method and repeat the call until you have all the data:

```
int openFileBytesNumber = (int)openFile1.Length;
int len = 0;
while (len < openFileBytesNumber) {
  int l = openFile1.Read(byteArray, len, openFileBytesNumber - len);
  if (l == 0) {
    // unexpended end of file error - better handle that
  }
  len += l:
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like when you query your database you are storing the entire result set in memory via DataSet. Consider using a SqlDataReader (or IDataReader for your database) instead of SqlDataAdapter and DataSet. This will allow you to have 1 row in memory at a time, instead of the entire result set.

Answer (score 0):

Your `FileStream` and any other objects implementing `IDisposable` need to be in `using` blocks:

```
using (var openFile1 = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
{
    blah, blah, blah
    .
    .
    .
    openFileBytesNumber = openFile1.Length;
    byteArray = new byte[openFileBytesNumber];
    openFile1.Read(byteArray, 0, (int)(openFileBytesNumber));
    fullByteString = Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray);
}
```